# Force Ionic's sideMenu to be scrolled top

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic with its SideMenu (standard template).

It works fine, however when I show the sidemenu, then I scroll it down (its pretty long), then I close it and try to open again it stays scrolled down.

Is it possible to always scroll it up when I open it?
My menu (base.html) template:

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-more" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-energized">
      <h1 class="title">Menu</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item menu-close href="#/app/overview" item-type="item-icon-left">
          <i class="icon ion-information-circled"></i>
          {{ 'overview' | translate }}
        </ion-item>

        <div class="item item-divider">
          {{ 'logout' | translate }}
        </div>
        <ion-item ng-click="logout()" item-type="item-icon-left">
          <i class="icon ion-power"></i>
          {{ 'logout' | translate }}
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Comment: It shows the scroll position same place where you left off after scrolling it downwards ?

Comment: @cafebabe1991 yes, exactly

Comment: Try to close the app completely as in , it should not be visible in the recently used apps menu, or try to force stop it.

Comment: You didn't understand my question. I need to programatically scroll up the sidebar each time I close it/open it. I need it to be on very top always when user shows it.

Comment: Look at this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/side-menu-scroll-to-top-every-time-it-opens/5982

Answer (score 1):

Try use $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();

HTML

```
<button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left" ng-click="toggleLeftSideMenu()"></button>
```

Controller

```
    $scope.toggleLeftSideMenu = function () {        

        $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollTop();            

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

**app.html:-**

```
   <ion-menu [content]="content" id="menu-up" (ionClose)="closingNavSlideUp()">Menu List 
   </ion-menu>
```

**app.com.ts:-**

```
   import { Content } from 'ionic-angular';
   export class projectName{
       @ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
       closingNavSlideUp() {
           this.content.scrollToTop();
       }
   }
```

**app.scss:**-

```
    ion-menu {
       &#menu-up{
           display: block !important;
           visibility: hidden;
       }
       &.show-menu {
           visibility: visible !important;
       }
    }
```